# Prove that $C_{3 \over 2}^n$ is bounded given $C_{a}^n = \frac{a(a-1)(a-2)\dots(a-n+1)}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds, monotone-functions

> Let: 
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> C_{a}^n = \frac{a(a-1)(a-2)\dots(a-n+1)}{n!}\\
> C_{a}^0 = 1
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Prove $C_{3 \over 2}^n$ is bounded.

I've started with finding a reduced formula:
$$
C_{3\over 2}^n = \frac{{3\over 2}\left({3\over 2} - 1\right)\left({3\over 2} - 2\right)\left({3\over 2} - 3\right)\cdots\left({3\over 2} - n+1\right)}{n!} =\\
= \frac{3\cdot 1 \cdot(-1)\cdot(-3)\cdots(3-2n)}{2^n\cdot n!} = \\
\frac{1}{2^n \cdot n!}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(5-2k\right)
$$

This seems to converge to $0$ and therefore the sequence should be bounded, but how do i formally show that using inequalities? Moreover the elements change their sign depending on $n$ is even/odd (should i consider absolute values?).

Please note the precalculus tag. Thank you!

Comment: Actually it was incorrect from the beginning. Last one is $5-2n$ Is correct.

Comment: The very last product expression is correct

Comment: An hint on this problem is that you should try finding upper bound of squares.

Comment: Note also that denominator can be rewritten as product of even numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should start from using the known expression of Gamma function:

$\Gamma(z)= \frac{\Gamma(z+n+1)}{z(z+1)....(z+n)}$  following that $z(z+1)....(z+n-1) =\frac{\Gamma(z+n+1)}{\Gamma(z) (n+z)}$

On the other hand:

$C_{a}^n = \frac{a(a-1)(a-2)\dots(a-n+1)}{n!}=(-1)^n\frac{(-a)(-a+1)(-a+2)\dots(-a+n-1)}{n!}$

If $z=-a=-\frac{3}{2}$ put it back to $\Gamma(z)$ we get:

$C_{\frac{3}{2}}^n =\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(n-\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(-\frac{3}{2}) (n-\frac{3}{2})}$

As $\Gamma(n-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}{(n-\frac{1}{2})}$ using that $\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{(2n)! \sqrt{\pi}}{4^n n!}$ and $\Gamma(-\frac{3}{2})=\frac{4\sqrt{\pi}}{3}$

We have the following:

$C_{\frac{3}{2}}^n =3\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\frac{1}{2n-3}$

We handle the even and odd terms separately and perform the ratio test for both terms:

$n={2m}$, if n - even and ${2m+1}$, if n - odd.

Let's take $\frac{C^{2m+2}_{\frac{3}{2}}}{C^{2m}_{\frac{3}{2}}}$ and $\frac{C^{2m+3}_{\frac{3}{2}}}{C^{2m+1}_{\frac{3}{2}}}$

After perform the simplifications we have:

$\frac{C^{2m+2}_{\frac{3}{2}}}{C^{2m}_{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{(4m-1)(4m-3)}{(4m+2)(4m+4)}\lt 1$ so the even terms are decreasing and tends to zero, because $C_{\frac{3}{2}}^{2m} \gt 0$

$\frac{C^{2m+3}_{\frac{3}{2}}}{C^{2m+1}_{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{(4m+1)(4m-1)}{(4m+6)(4m+4)}\lt 1$ so the odd terms are increasing and tends to zero, because $C_{\frac{3}{2}}^{2m+1} \lt 0$

So $C_{\frac{3}{2}}^n \rightarrow{0}$ if $n\rightarrow {\infty}$.

Comment: After you have $C_{\frac{3}{2}}^n =3\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n-1}\frac{1}{2n-3}$, you can use $\binom {2n} n\leq 4^n$ to show $C_{\frac{3}{2}}^n $ approaches $0$.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see in that moment, thank you.

Comment: This approach is nice, definitely +1, however gamma function is defined in terms of an integral being a generalization of a factorial concept. Apart from integrals gamma function may also be defined with the help of limits which also falls out of precalculus scope.

Comment: I have read your answer once again but more carefully, this definitely answers the question since Gamma function is not required based on the second part of your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the notices, best regards,

Answer (score 1):

After some pondering i'm going to try to answer this myself.

I've been thinking about considering two cases for $n$ is odd and $n$ is even. Start with even $n$. We know that for any $n \ge 2 \implies C_{3/2}^n > 0$ in case $n$ is even. Lets inspect a subsequence for even indices:

$$
C_{3/2}^n = \frac{1}{2^nn!}\prod_{k=1}^n(5-2k) \\
C_{3/2}^{n+2} = \frac{1}{2^{n+2}(n+2)!}\prod_{k=1}^{n+2}(5-2k)
$$
Consider the fraction:

$$
\frac{C_{3/2}^{n+2}}{C_{3/2}^n} = \frac{2^nn!}{2^{n+2}(n+2)!}(5-2(n+1))(5-2(n+2)) = \\
=\frac{1}{2^2(n+1)(n+2)}\cdot(3-2n)(1-2n) = \frac{(2n-3)(2n-1)}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}
$$

Clearly this is less than $1$ and hence the sequence is decreasing towards $0^+$. With that being said the maximum is obtained for $n=1$ which is $3 \over 2$. Also note that for odd indices the value for $C_{3/2}^n < 0$.

Now consider the case for odd $n$:

$$
C_{3/2}^n = -\left|\frac{1}{2^nn!}\prod_{k=1}^n(5-2k)\right| \\
C_{3/2}^{n+2} = -\left|\frac{1}{2^{n+2}(n+2)!}\prod_{k=1}^{n+2}(5-2k)\right|
$$

Now using the results from the case for even $n$ we obtain that:

$$
\frac{|C_{3/2}^{n+2}|}{|C_{3/2}^{n}|} < 1
$$

At the same time $C_{3/2}^n$ for odd $n$ is less than $0$ hence for odd $n$:

$$
0 < C_{3/2}^{n} < C_{3/2}^{n+2}
$$

This means $C_{3/2}^n$ is increasing and tending to $0^-$. Thus the minimum value of $C_{3/2}^n$ is obtained at $n=3$

Compiling both cases gives us that:

$$
C_{3/2}^3< C_{3/2}^n < C_{3/2}^1
$$

or:

$$
−0.0625 < C_{3/2}^n < {3 \over 2}
$$

I would appreciate any comments on the given approach.